# Select difference between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to list four columns, date, hourly count, daily count and difference between two counts.

I have used union all for two tables, but I am getting 2rows as shown in the image:

[image]

```
Select a.date, a.hour,b.daily,sum(a.hour-b.daily)
from (select date,count(*) hour,''daily 
From table a union all select '' hour,count(*) daily from table b) 
Group by date, daily, hourly..
```

Please suggest to me a solution.

Comment: Please do not post your data as image, because it is hard to process it and it cannot be reused (for `create table`, for example). Check [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question. Also I believe your statement doesn't work, because you have different column number in `UNION` operator and have no `GROUP BY` to use `count` aggregate function in subquery, so update your question with working code. And finally, never use reserved keywords for object names like table named `table` or date field named `date`. It produces lots of errors.

Comment: Stop cramming your code together. At the very LEAST, make it readable. Develop good habits - be the professional others expect.  Storing dates as strings (or numbers) is a bad idea - especially when you combine it with empty strings in the same column of your union.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the code supplied uses a `UNION` to achieve the output.  This would be better served by using a `JOIN` of some kind.

The result is the total number of rows in `table_a` grouped by the `date` subtracted from the total number of rows in `table_b` grouped by the `date`.

This code is untested but should give a good indication of how to achieve this:

```
SELECT  a.date,
        a.hour,
        ISNULL(b.daily, 0) AS daily,
        a.hour - ISNULL(b.daily) AS difference
  FROM  (
        SELECT  date,
                COUNT(*) AS hour
          FROM  table_a
          GROUP BY date
        ) a
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT  date,
                       COUNT(*) AS daily
                 FROM  table_b
                 GROUP BY date
               ) b ON b.date = a.date
  ORDER BY a.date;
```

This works by:

1. Calculating the count per date in `table_a`.
2. Calculating the count per date in `table_b`.
3. Joining all results from `table_a` with those matching in `table_b`.
4. Outputting the `date`, the `hour` from `table_a`, the `daily` (or 0 if `NULL`) from `table_b`, and the difference between the two.

**Notes:**

- I have renamed `table a` and `table b` to `table_a` and `table_b`. I presume these are not the actual table names
- An `INNER JOIN` may be preferable if you only want results that have matching `date` columns in both tables.  Using the `LEFT JOIN` will return all results from `table_a` regardless of whether `table_b` has an entry.
- I'm not convinced that `date` is an allowed column name but I have reproduced it in the code as per the example given by OP.

Comment: It is arguable. In most cases it is better to use `UNION` and `GROUP BY` if it solves the problem instead of `JOIN`, because in general it performs better (can be parallelized, less operations to calculate results, no need to care about key fields etc). For PLAN vs FACT analysis it works fine with `UNION`.

Comment: @astentx Could you explain why, because I'm afraid in this case I don't see the logic in that

Comment: I've updated the comment. I'm sorry for hitting enter instead of letter

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine.  Your `group by` columns are not correct:

```
Select date, sum(hourly) as hourly, sum(daily) as daily,
       sum(hourly) - sum(daily) as diff
from ((select date, count(*) as hourly, 0 as daily 
       from table a
       group by date
      ) union all
      (select date, 0 as hourly, count(*) as daily
       from table b
       group by date
      ) 
     ) ab
group by date;
```

The key idea is that the outer query aggregates only by `date` -- and you still need aggregation functions there as well.

You have other errors in your subquery, such as missing `group by`s and `date` columns.  I assume those are transcription errors.